# SQL "BETWEEN" command gives data type mismatch

Tags: sql, ms-access, type-mismatch

So I have the code

```
INSERT INTO EMP_1 ( EMP_NUM, EMP_LNAME, EMP_FNAME, EMP_INITIAL, EMP_HIREDATE, JOB_CODE )
SELECT EMP_NUM, EMP_LNAME, EMP_FNAME, EMP_INITIAL, EMP_HIREDATE, JOB_CODE
FROM EMPLOYEE
WHERE EMP_NUM BETWEEN 103 AND 109;
```

and I get the error "Data type mismatch in criteria expression."

I don't get the error when I don't have that WHERE ... BETWEEN line; it adds all 18 lines just as expected. But I only want to add rows for where EMP_NUM is between 103-109. EMP_NUM member in EMP_1 table and EMPLOYEE table are both of the same type: Char(3).

*(Also, I would expect EMP_NUM should be a number, not a string, but this is a homework assignment and what do I know)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with MS-Access, but it looks like it is complaining that `EMP_NUM` is of type `CHAR(3)` and you are asking it to be compared to two `INT` values.

Try changing the integer values by character ones: `WHERE EMP_NUM BETWEEN "103" AND "109";`

Comment: You're absolutely right. I'm new to SQL but I understand now that casting is still just as important. I'm trying to compare a string to numbers, so one of them has to change their type. The quotes turn the numbers into strings, which is the better solution than recasting EMP_NUM.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Val()](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/val-function-e5e1f21b-22f9-41c9-bd0a-fe55b767f603) to cast those `EMP_NUM` strings to numbers for comparison with your numeric `BETWEEN` value range:

```sql
WHERE Val(EMP_NUM) BETWEEN 103 AND 109
```

Comment: This works, but it also works to put 103 and 109 in quotes to make them strings instead of values. Since they're numbers and I want to compare them by value, turning them into strings might get wonky in certain situations, but in this case, I'd rather just put the numbers in quotes. Thanks though, your answer does work!